# Cannot install zeromq package from chris-lea/zeromq in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, aptitude

I ran:

```
%> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/zeromq
%> sudo aptitude update
%> sudo aptitude install zeromq3 php-zeromq # result: zeromq3 - no such package found
```

I tried restarting my system, running `sudo apt-get update`, restarting again, but in all cases I get the same package not found result.

I have verified that these packages exist for 12.04 by filtering for `Precise` from the "Published in:" dropdown at the [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/zeromq?field.series_filter=precise) page.

What do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ZeroMQ3 cannot be installed with a single `zeromq3` package. I don't know why. You can still install ZeroMQ3 with 3 packages (`libzmq3-dbg`, `libzmq3-dev` and `libzmq3`) separately. So the complete solution is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/zeromq
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dbg libzmq3-dev libzmq3
```

How to know these packages are `libzmq3-dbg`, `libzmq3-dev` and `libzmq3`? You can go to https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/zeromq and click *View package details*, then click the package you desired. You'll see them in *Built packages* section.

Comment: This no longer works. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and that repository gives a 404.

Comment: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.